# Transducer impedance decreased when Amplifier is connected

Tags: operational-amplifier, impedance, transducer

I am trying to measure beam pattern and impedance curve of a transducer from 70 to 120 khz. To get a nice plot, i have to use an amplifier(op-amp +-14Vs and Gain=14db) between a Signal Generator(Whose Max Amp. output is 4Vpp) and the transducer. The correct impedance of the transducer lies around 500 Ohm between 80 to 100kHz.
When i connect the amplifier(with Gain=14db) between Sig Gen. and transducer, the impedance decreases to around 100 ohm. The output Voltage coming out of amplifier is around 20Vpp. The question is why is there decrease in impedance.

Here is my sketch of the set up:- In first, the resistor is in front of the op amp THS3095 and in the next set up, the resistor is behind op amp. the resistor was used just to measure voltage drop. The impedance observed when resistor is before op amp is 50 ohm and when resistor is after op amp is 150 ohm.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Show your circuit. Add data sheet links. Explain how you go about measuring impedance.

Comment: *When i connect the amplifier...the impedance decreases* Obviously the amplifier influences the impedance. Show a schematic so we can see if you connected the amplifier correctly and/or the impedance change is to be expected (I think it is).